# What is a suitable data mining model to find the best Hospital?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, data-mining, linear-regression

I have a Hospital ratings data-set and need to find best hospital when I just broke my leg. So what is the best data mining model that I can use and how to 
find which model is better?

[https://www.kaggle.com/center-for-medicare-and-medicaid/hospital-ratings#*=*](https://www.kaggle.com/center-for-medicare-and-medicaid/hospital-ratings#_=_)

Comment: What data do you have? What are the variables/dimensions?

Comment: Variables are in https://www.kaggle.com/center-for-medicare-and-medicaid/hospital-ratings#_=_

Answer (score 1):

This is really up to you to design. You need to attach a weight to each of the variables you have, which is how you attach importance to that variable.

Is the hospital location a limiting factor? Maybe you can only hobble 5 miles on your broken leg, or maybe you're a baller and can book your private jet to Hollywood.

If you don't have a way to connect with an API to determine distance based on your location and the hospital address, then you'll just have to throw out location altogether.

If you just broke your leg, timeliness of care is probably pretty important. But if you want to get a boob job, then you probably don't mind waiting a month or two as long as it's done really well.

In this case, effectiveness of care is probably the most valuable variable. I would start with just that, then work on adding in more variables and refining your answer. What happens if two hospitals have equally good effectiveness? Then patient satisfaction might be the next most important, etc.